# Schedule refresh Tableau desktop 10.4 and schedule refresh at a particular day/time

Tags: tableau-api

I have couple of questions-

I have one workbook with 2 dashboards published on Tableau server-
One dashboard has Excel sheet as data source, which is located in the local system and other dashboard has an oracle DB as data source.

Questions- 
1- If I schedule a full extract refresh at Midnight when my system is off, will the refresh be successful?
I understand irrespective of my system being ON/OFF the Data Base based refresh will not be a problem. what will happen to the overall dashboard refresh?

2- This is based on the Tableau desktop- 
Below is the screen shot of Tableau desktop 10.4, how do I schedule the refresh on a particular date of the month? (For an example, I want to schedule a refresh on every 5th of the month at 4:00 am)
Similarly, i see the same on my Tableau Server as well.

[image: Tableau 10.4 schedule refresh screenshot]

As far as I remember until beginning of 2018, even Tableau 10.3 had a provision to schedule extract refresh in a customized manner, like select any date/day/time.

Please advise

Answer (score 0):

1. I think this needs some clarification but if your Tableau instance is shutdown then extracts will not refresh. I am pretty sure they will not be queued up to run upon system boot up either. Server needs to be running at the time of the scheduled task for that task to run.
2. You can create this type of schedule as a site or server admin. The image you are showing will include the schedule you want but only after it has been setup.

go to schedules/new schedule:

[image]

[image]

Now when you go back to the schedule list you posted, you will see the new schedule under the name you give it in the setup screen.